# Transforming T4 from command line doesn't add generated files to csproj

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, code-generation, build-automation, t4

I am trying to transform a T4 template from command line using [TextTransform.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb126245(v=vs.100).aspx) with the following command line:

`"%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\TextTemplating\10.0\TextTransform.exe"`
**-out** `.\MyProj\MyT4.cs`
**-I** `"%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Entity Framework Tools\Templates\Includes"`
**-a** `!NamespaceHint!MyNameSpace`
**-dp** `T4VSHost!Microsoft.Data.Entity.Design.VisualStudio.Directives.FallbackT4VSHostProcessor!"%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\Microsoft.Data.Entity.Design.dll"`
`.\MyProj\MyT4.tt`

**Results:**

1. No error messages
2. The %ERRORLEVEL% is 0 on completion.
3. The files are generated
4. The .csproj does not change

The problem is point 4. This may be expected, since the .csproj isn't a part of the above command line, however, I can't find any parameters which can accept it.

***What am I doing wrong or what should I be doing instead?***

P.S. When I use the button in Visual Studio the process works as excepted (new files are added to project).

Comment: Just a comment; I personally never bother with generating many files from one template. This question is one of the reasons. Now you might not be able to chose because of requirements surrounding you but for the future and others this is my belief: 1 template to 1 file => less problems.

Comment: The files are generated using database data and are used for transforming generic data wearhouse into strongly typed domain driven structures. The number of these files is not constant. I do have one ttinclude file per output file type, one main ttinclude file for orchestrating all the parts and the tt file just passes parameters to the orchestrator ttinclude file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved using the following method:

1. Added these parameters to command line:

   **-a** `!!ProjPath!.\MyProj\MyProj.csproj` **-a** `!!T4Path!.\MyProj\MyT4.tt`
2. Changed the include directory parameter to a local path:

   **-I** `".\Dependencies"`
3. Copied `EF.Utility.CS.ttinclude` to that path and made the following changes:

3.1. Replaced:

```
    public static EntityFrameworkTemplateFileManager Create(object textTransformation)
    {
        DynamicTextTransformation transformation = DynamicTextTransformation.Create(textTransformation);
        IDynamicHost host = transformation.Host;

#if !PREPROCESSED_TEMPLATE
        if (host.AsIServiceProvider() != null)
        {
            return new VsEntityFrameworkTemplateFileManager(transformation);
        }
#endif
        return new EntityFrameworkTemplateFileManager(transformation);
    }
```

with

```
    public static EntityFrameworkTemplateFileManager Create(object textTransformation)
    {
        DynamicTextTransformation transformation = DynamicTextTransformation.Create(textTransformation);
        IDynamicHost host = transformation.Host;

#if !PREPROCESSED_TEMPLATE
        if (host.AsIServiceProvider() != null)
        {
            return new VsEntityFrameworkTemplateFileManager(transformation);
        }
#endif
        return new EFTemplateFileManagerPlus(transformation);
    }
```

(Last return has the change)

Add added this class to the file:

```
private sealed class EFTemplateFileManagerPlus : EntityFrameworkTemplateFileManager
{
        private Action<IEnumerable<string>> projectSyncAction;
        private readonly string _projPath;
        private readonly string _t4Name;

        public EFTemplateFileManagerPlus(object textTemplating)
            : base(textTemplating)
        {
            var projPath = _textTransformation.Host.ResolveParameterValue("", "", "ProjPath");
            var t4Path = _textTransformation.Host.ResolveParameterValue("", "", "T4Path");
            _projPath = System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(projPath);
            _t4Name = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(t4Path);

            projectSyncAction = files => SyncCsProjFile(_projPath, _t4Name, files);
        }

        public static void SyncCsProjFile(string csProjFilePath, string t4FileName, IEnumerable<string> files)
        {
            files = files.Select(f => System.IO.Path.GetFileName(f)).Distinct().ToList();

            var csProjDocument = new XmlDocument();
            csProjDocument.Load(csProjFilePath);

            var root = csProjDocument.DocumentElement;

            XmlElement itemGroup = root.ChildNodes.OfType<XmlElement>()
                .Where(n => n.Name == "ItemGroup")
                .SelectMany(n => n.ChildNodes.OfType<XmlNode>()
                    .Where(c => c.Name == "Compile")
                    )
                .Select(c => c.ParentNode)
                .FirstOrDefault() as XmlElement;

            if (itemGroup == null)
            {
                itemGroup = csProjDocument.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "ItemGroup", null) as XmlElement;
                root.AppendChild(itemGroup);
            }

            var codeFiles = itemGroup.ChildNodes.OfType<XmlElement>()
                .Where(c =>
                    c.Name == "Compile"
                    && c.HasAttribute("Include") && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(c.GetAttribute("Include")))
                .ToList();

            var dependantFiles = codeFiles
                .Where(f =>
                    f.ChildNodes.OfType<XmlElement>().Any(c =>
                        c.Name == "DependentUpon"
                        && c.InnerText == t4FileName)
                ).ToList();

            // Remove redundant files
            foreach (var node in dependantFiles)
            {
                if (!files.Contains(node.GetAttribute("Include")))
                    itemGroup.RemoveChild(node);
            }

            // Add missing files
            foreach (var name in files)
            {
                if (!dependantFiles.Any(node => node.GetAttribute("Include") == name))
                {
                    var node = csProjDocument.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "Compile", null) as XmlElement;
                    node.SetAttribute("Include", name);
                    itemGroup.AppendChild(node);

                    var node2 = csProjDocument.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "DependentUpon", null) as XmlElement;
                    node2.InnerText = t4FileName;
                    node.AppendChild(node2);
                }
            }

            SaveClean(csProjDocument, csProjFilePath);
        }

        static private void SaveClean(XmlDocument doc, string path)
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
            settings.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
            settings.Indent = true;
            settings.IndentChars = "  ";
            settings.NewLineChars = "\r\n";
            settings.NewLineHandling = NewLineHandling.Replace;
            settings.NamespaceHandling = NamespaceHandling.OmitDuplicates;
            using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(sb, settings))
            {
                doc.Save(writer);
            }

            var newXml = sb.ToString().Replace("encoding=\"utf-16\"", "encoding=\"utf-8\"").Replace(" xmlns=\"\"", string.Empty);
            System.IO.File.WriteAllText(path, newXml, Encoding.UTF8);
        }

        public override IEnumerable<string> Process(bool split)
        {
            var generatedFileNames = base.Process(split);

            projectSyncAction.EndInvoke(projectSyncAction.BeginInvoke(generatedFileNames, null, null));

            return generatedFileNames;
        }
    }
```

Now the project file sync works using `TextTransform.exe` too.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the command line host cannot change the .csproj. Only the VS host can do it, through the access to the DTE object.

Comment: So TextTransform.exe can't be configured to access the EnvDTE? Any way to access the transform via the VS host during build process it that case?